# How to get the number of allocated bytes in Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, mono

Recently I have been working on adding more accurate Memory Diagnostics to BenchmarkDotNet (not based on ETW, which notifies about allocation when more than 100KB was allocated). For the classic .NET I have used `AppDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize` and for .NET Core (netcoreapp1.1) the `GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread()` method which was [recently introduced](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/12489).

The problem is that Mono does not implement these methods. It [throws NotImplementedException](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs#L1663).

Is there any way to obtain the number of allocated bytes for Mono?

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult to *add*, by wrapping the [`mono_gc_alloc_*`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/f458d55ec2dd9aa1e0f08327d4483f18412d4772/mono/metadata/gc-internals.h) functions, but there doesn't appear to be any facility yet within Mono itself, let alone one it could expose.